# Javascript/PHP - reCaptcha styles are broken

Tags: php, javascript, styles, recaptcha

I'm using reCaptcha in this form I build, but for some reason, it loses it's styling...
Does anyone have a clue why?
The form: -link no longer needed-

The code for the form:

```
<td align="center" colspan="2">
    <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/ var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : "clean", lang: "en" }; /*]]>*/</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LfExcoSAAAAAFuAzQEMIDXCkWN3Y9nRd9uLfetc"></script>
    <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6LfExcoSAAAAAFuAzQEMIDXCkWN3Y9nRd9uLfetc" height="250px" width="100%" frameborder="0" title="CAPTCHA test"></iframe><br />
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" id="tswcaptcha" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
</td>
```

It just doesn't make sense that the style is broken, because I've got it to work on another site... Could it be because I load the reCaptcha form using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the AJAX API for the ReCaptcha, which works like a charm!

More info about there here:
http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX

Answer (score 0):

i cant even see where the reCaptcha should get its style from?

[reCaptcha Docs](http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html)

Comment: As far as I know, the reCaptcha gets it's style from the fact I set the options: { theme : "clean", lang: "en" }, am I right?

Comment: that is correct. But i  dont see it as user on the rendered HTML page.

If you goto your page, and watch the html source of the iframe, there's no style. But on fx http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore there's a style in the head of the iframe page.

But it's probably as you have suggested yourself, when you load it with jQuery the script doesn't execute.

Try wrap the reCaptcha init code into a function and call that function after loading he new form?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the code didn't show up in the code aswell, I'm not really sure how I would wrap the reCaptcha code in a function, as it is just an iFrame I'm linking to [which contains the recaptcha]...

Comment: function foo (){ var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : "clean", lang: "en" }; }    and then call that function (foo) from some code executes when the reCaptcha has been loaded.